# Noise estimation in LTE using bandpass filter

Tags: noise, lte

Can noise estimation in LTE be done using bandpass filter?
As per my study in wireless systems to estimate noise power, if pilot sequence is known is done as |y(k)-p(k)h(k)|^2, where p(k) is pilot sequence, h(k) is channel and y(k) is received data at receiver.

But I was going through the code used in my project for LTE chain there for noise estimation they are estimating noise as sum|conv(p(t),h(3t)| where p(t) is pilots (12 pilots for 1.4 MHz BW) h is 35 tap band pass filter.

How can we get noise power using this?